# Setting a Remote Host with MySQLImport

Tags: mysql, mysqlimport

I'm having trouble with mysqlimport taking in a host argument: It appears as if it selectively accepts a hostname.

```
mysqlimport --compress --user=SOMEUSER --host=mysql.spr.local --password=SOMEPASSWORD --    delete --ignore-lines=1 --fields-terminated-by=';' --fields-enclosed-by='"' --lines-    terminated-by='\n' cicu ./ResearchData.csv 

mysqlimport: Error: 1045 Access denied for user 'SOMEUSER'@'oban.spr.local' (using password: YES)
```

However, if I select a different server:

```
mysqlimport --compress --user=SOMEUSER --host=deepthought.spr.local --password=SOMEPASS -- delete --ignore-lines=1 --fields-terminated-by=';' --fields-enclosed-by='"' --lines-terminated-by='\n' cicu ./ResearchData.csv
mysqlimport: Error: 2003 Can't connect to MySQL server on 'deepthought.spr.local' (111)
```

deepthought doesn't have a mysql server on it, using it as a host import is meant purely to show that mysqlimport seems to accept a host input if I give it a different server.

nslookup returns records for both server.. so what could cause mysqlimport seemingly ignore my host argument and default to localhost (oban.spr.local) in the first case but recognize my host input in the second case? Ive also tried giving the IP address of mysql.spr.local instead and still defaulted to oban.spr.local

Comment: Can you send us the output of nslookup for both server ?

Comment: It is not ignoring your host setting. MySQL sees that you are connecting FROM oban.spr.local. The host argument specifies where you want to connect TO. You should give permissions to SOMEUSER@oban.spr.local if you are connecting from that location.